# cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord

Tags: java, avro

I have the autogenerated Agr.java schema file from avro. And I am seeing this error when attempting to cast to a `GenericRecord`.

> *(FileStreamer.java:processFile(181)) - java.lang.ClassCastException: records.Agr cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord*

It gets thrown from here--

```
Class avroClass = Class.forName("records.Agr");

GenericRecord avroClassObject = (GenericRecord) avroClass.newInstance();
```

I am able to run this successfully on the server but not locally on my windows machine. I am using the same build/.pom/etc.

Any insights would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with my IDE setup, I needed to specify the classpath of the module in the run configuration.